# PUT/POST Request with CloudFront vs S3TA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have been dealing with data transfer from/to CloudFront and S3 (via Transfer Acceleration). I know some of you will suggest using S3TA but I want to achieve it through CloudFront for some reason.

According to AWS FAQ;

> Q: How should I choose between Transfer Acceleration and Amazon CloudFront’s PUT/POST?

> A: Transfer Acceleration optimizes the TCP protocol and adds additional intelligence between the client and the S3 bucket, making Transfer Acceleration a better choice if a higher throughput is desired. If you have objects that are smaller than 1GB or if the data set is less than 1GB in size, you should consider using Amazon CloudFront's PUT/POST commands for optimal performance.

Basically, my React app will allow users to upload/download files. Size of each individual file won't exceed 100MB. So it is wise to go with CloudFront PUT/POST request rather than S3 Transfer Acceleration. Also CloudFront is cheaper.

Now question is, how can I achieve uploading files with CloudFront PUT/POST request. I believe it is possible via CloudFront signed URLs but I can't find out how to make it work. I have read tens of articles and documentations about it but none of them explains even a bit of implementation. All they tell about is what CloudFront is about. Also, I am pretty sure you all know AWS documentation for JavaScript sucks.

AWS is great but I am exhausted dealing with it and if I can't find any solution here, I will be done with AWS for sure!

Comment: Why is CloudFront cheaper?

Comment: As long as I remember, with Transfer Acceleration, price per upload/download costs more comparing CloudFront data transfer. Also CloudFront provides free 50GB of data transfer for the first 12 months.

Comment: Be aware that `Each time you use S3 Transfer Acceleration to upload an object, we will check whether the service is likely to be faster than a regular Amazon S3 transfer. If we determine that it is not likely to be faster than a regular Amazon S3 transfer of the same object to the same destination AWS Region, we will not charge for that use of S3 Transfer Acceleration for that transfer, and may bypass the S3 Transfer Acceleration system for that upload.` If you have a lot of data transfer every month, S3TA could be cheaper actually.

Comment: Yes, it could be cheaper if TA is not used often but I still prefer CF since people talking about latency issues with TA uploads.

Comment: From what I've read for files your size TA is not the right choice. I'm in the same position and am researching this now too.  Did you find a solution or setup guide? @AltugKarabas

Comment: Sorry for late answer. To be honest, event though there is no proper guide for implementation I figured out it was all about making a fetch call to a pre-signed URL that you got from your back-end. But it is important to get signed URLs via S3, not CloudFront. And when you want to make a fetch call, you need to replace the S3 URL with CloudFront URL. That way you can upload files via CloudFront fast instead of dealing with TA. Good luck!